# Ajax successfully fetching URL but not updating page, instead get [object HTMLDivElement]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

So I'm trying to make a next/prev buttons using javascript, and have used a DynamicPage script to help test this. I've only changed the start of the URL variable in *pagenumber.js* however will essentially give the same message. I want to be able to click next/prev, which will then update the main body with another page of content via AJAX.

I checked the console and no errors are present, and opening the *Network* tab of the inspector shows the URL which I'm aiming to open is actually being loaded, however the container just displays
`[object HTMLDivElement]`

I've never properly used AJAX before so chances are I'm doing something wrong. If somebody could please point me in the right direction I'd be much appreciative!

Thanks.

My *pagenumber.js* is as follows:

```
var i = 0;

function loadPage(i) {
     /* IMPORTANT: ENSURE var url equals the exact domain and location of inductions OR it will fail    */
     var url = "https://example.com/inductions/induction-page-" + i + ".html";
     fetch(url).then(content => {
         document.getElementById("guts").innerHTML = guts;
         document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = i;
     });
}

function incPage() {
     i++;
     if (i > 10) i = 1;
     loadPage(i);
}

function decPage() {
     i--;
     if (i < 1) i = 10;
     loadPage(i);
}
```

My main HTML is as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/dynamicpage.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/pagenumber.js'></script>

<div id="container">
    <div id="page-wrap">

        <header>
            <a id="decc"><input type="button" value="Previous" id="dec" onclick="decPage();"/></a>
            <a id="incc"><input type="button" value="Next" id="inc" onclick="incPage();"/></a>
            Page: <label id="display"></label>
        </header>

    <section id="main-content">
        <div id="guts">
            <h3>Initial Induction Page</h3>
            <p>This is initial content on loading main HTML doc. This content will change when hitting next/prev buttons.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    </div>
```

Also, the *dynamicpage.js* is as follows:

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log(window.location.hash);
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

Comment: In the pagenumber.js, there is a line saying `document.getElementById("guts").innerHTML = guts;`. May I know where the variable `guts` is defined at?

Comment: It's stated in the HTML, defined as a div, both dynamicpage.js and pagenumber.js make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

`fetch` returns a [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. This object tells you how the server responded and allows you to extract the data you received in multiple ways. Since you use `innerHTML` to set the newly downloaded data you'll need to use the [`text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) method of the response. This will return a promise that when finished presents the result in a string. And you should use that result to set your `innerHTML` with on the `guts` element.

If the content returned from the response is a full HTML page and you need a part from it, use the [DOMParser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), parse the string to HTML and use `querySelector` to select the element which you need to content from.

```
var i = 0;
var guts = document.getElementById("guts");
var display = document.getElementById("display");

function loadPage(i) {
  /* IMPORTANT: ENSURE var url equals the exact domain and location of inductions OR it will fail    */
  let url = "https://example.com/inductions/induction-page-" + i + ".html";
  fetch(url).then(response => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      return response.text();
    }
    throw new Error(`Error occurred fetching ${url}. Status: ${response.status});
  }).then(getGutsFromContent).then(content => {
    guts.innerHTML = content;
    display.textContent = i;
  });
}

function getGutsFromContent(content) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const doc = parser.parseFromString(content, 'text/html');
  const guts = doc.querySelector('#guts');
  if (guts !== null) {
    return guts.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Starting to make more sense now. How would I make  the `content` equal to the "guts" of the other pages which will display on the main page through AJAX?

Comment: You mean you want to use only the content of the `<div id="guts">` of the other pages that you receive in your `fetch` response?

Comment: Yeah that's it, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Upon running the page, I get an error saying
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at VM194 pagenumber.js:32"

Specifically, the line at `guts.innerHTML = content;`

Comment: Then your guts div is not in the page.